# Compatibility of Mac MySQL workbench 8.0.31 and MariaDB 10.5 possible?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

Every time I go to connect to a remote MariaDB server it just fails and in the logs it says

```
18:32:43 [ERR][      WBContext]: Unsupported server version: mariadb.org binary distribution 10.5.15-MariaDB-1:10.5.15+maria~focal-log
```

Is this expected or is something else happening?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1435874/mysql-workbench-giving-an-error-unsupported-operating-system-when-running-unde

Comment: You can fake MariaDB's server version with the system variable [version](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#version), however may be consequences for other applications if they depend on `select version()` and make decisions based on the setting provided.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried these with some success... I've decided to go with dBeaver for now....when I have more time I'll revisit this.